# Support Physics Problem Solving on Area 51

Tags: discussion, support

I know there are many Physics enthusiasts on Astronomy SE. I would invite them to have a look at the [new site proposal on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/103955/physics-problem-solving/103964#103964)

Presently Physics SE isn't meant for problem-solving. It is more about specific physics concepts. The new site wishes to be what Physics SE isn't i.e. a platform to discuss various ways of solving a problem and helping users find out their mistakes while solving. [See the meta post on Physics SE to get a better idea.](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9303/new-site-proposal-specifically-for-problem-solving-in-physics-on-area-51)

At the moment we lack followers on the proposal. But I think it can be a successful site. Do have a look and leave your suggestions on the meta post. Thank you.

Comment: As SE employees have killed the proposal on Area51, that community is now living outside the SE network here: http://physicsproblems.nfshost.com